# Unable to get key from a Guava MultiMap

Tags: java, guava

I have the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean putAll(Multimap<? extends Index, ? extends V> multimap) {
    for (Index index : multimap.keySet()) {
        putAll(index, multimap.get(index));
    }
}
```

Where `multimap.get(index)` is a compilation error:

> The method get(capture#5-of ? extends Index) in the type Multimap is not applicable for the arguments (Index)

Have I stumbled upon a famous generics gotcha? I don't quiet see what the problem can be.

Side note: I'm building a class that extends SetMultiMap because I have specific key matching requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you put in a `Multimap<FooIndex, Integer>`. Then you've got:

```
Multimap<FooIndex, Integer> map = ...;
Index plainIndex = ...;
Integer value = map.get(plainIndex);
```

That's a type failure, because `Multimap.get` takes a `Key`. I suspect you need to make this method generic:

```
@Override
public <Key extends Index> boolean putAll(Multimap<Key, ? extends V> multimap) {
    for (Key index : multimap.keySet()) {
        putAll(index, multimap.get(index));
    }
}
```

(I haven't tested it, but that makes more sense, IMO.)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I had never used generics before a method return type, just learned something new :) Still, in this case, this is the same as `public boolean putAll(Multimap<Index, ? extends V> multimap)`, right? Either way, the problem's understood thanks!. Only problem is, this `putAll` method no longer overrides the `putAll` in `SetMultimap<Index, V>`. I need to use the original interface and I'll change the implementation to make it fit.

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the get method is

```
get(K key)
```

Your Multimap is declared as

```
Multimap<? extends Index, ? extends V> multimap
```

So you don't know the type of the key. You know that it is or that it extends `Index`, but you don't know its type. So passing it an instance of `Index` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just using a regular `Multimap` and `Equivalence.wrap`-ing your keys?